# Помогите решить задачу (массивы) по JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите написать код, который принимает от пользователя фамилию, имя и отчество, а затем выводит на экран фамилию и инициалы (без пробела между инициалами).
Совсем запуталась....
Спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 2):

Допустим так

```js
let fio = [
  'Иванов',
  'Иван',
  'Иванович'
];

console.info(fio[0]+' '+fio[1][0]+'.'+fio[2][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Фамилию просто выводите. А инициалы можно сделать с помощью функции обрезки строки str.substr(a, b), где str - ваша строка (фамилия или отчество), a - начало подстроки, b - конец подстроки. В вашем случае a = 0, b = 1, то есть ваша функция получения инициала из фамилии или отчества будет выглядеть так: str.substr(0, 1)